# Acessar atributo de um objeto JS usando como key a chave de outro atributo

Tags: javascript, objetos, propriedade

Estou tentando pegar o valor dentro de um determinado objeto usando a key de outro objeto: Ex:

Eu tenho os objetos:

```
var obj1 = { id:'gh73f'}

var obj2 = {
    gh73f : 123,
    h39sg : 764,
    c9wer : 921
}
```

Eu tentei:

```
var valor = obj2[obj1.id];
```

e

```
var valor = obj2[obj1[id]];
```

Em nenhum dos casos eu consigo pegar o valor da key `gh73f` do `obj2`.

Comment: No firefox, a primeira forma `var valor = obj2[obj1.id]` funcionou normalmente... Já para a segunda forma funcionar, deveria ser `var valor = obj2[obj1['id']]`.

Comment: A primeira forma deveria funcionar em todo e qualquer interpretador de Javascript. Você não conseguiu com algum navegador específico, ou em algum motor como o node.js?

Comment: A primeira tentativa realmente deveria funcionar

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte use o `eval`, monte a string e depois de o `eval` para ele executar como código:

```
var valor = eval("obj2."+obj1.id);
```

Comment: Isso é um tiro de canhão para matar uma mosca.

Comment: @Renan sim, mas você tem alguma solução melhor? se tiver por favor compartilhe com a gente.

Comment: Veja os comentários na pergunta.

Comment: @Renan mas pelo menos a mosca morre é melhor do que a mosca ter muitos filhotes como no filme Godzilla que as baratas gigantes tinha muitos filhos mas o Godzilla acabou com todos e o Godzilla seria o `eval` e o problema seria a barata gigante, intende?

Comment: Porque me deram negativo? me diga o que tem de errado com a minha resposta?